# Returning key of new post from firebase returns null

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

### **Problem**

I am trying to push a value to firebase, and then retrieve to key so I can easily edit the post later on. What should happen in the post is that myKey will equal the newly created key, but what is actually happening is that nothing is getting returned.

This was coded in react native.

### **Code**

```
var myMessageRef = firebase.database().ref('users/'+expoID+'/chats').push();

myMessageRef.set({
  //...
}).then(()=>{
  myKey = myMessageRef.key; 
})
```

Comment: try var key = myMessageRef.key; after your first line

Comment: You can try [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) example

Comment: @Ayudh your solution works, thanks! I am unaware though, if a comment has the correct solution how do I mark it as correct?

Comment: I'll add an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#getting-the-unique-key-generated-by-push

we can see that .push() generates a unique key. The same is not said for .set() Therefore, add

```
var myKey = myMessageRef.key;
```

after your first line
and you should be good to go